Pre-populate belongsTo resource in Laravel Nova new model
In Laravel Nova, when creating a new resource (My case Programme::class) I need to sometimes pass a related model ID to prepopulate a relationship (One of my 4 relationships I need to set is term(), belongsTo Term::class).
From another view, I need to add a link with term_id to create a new Programme model with the term() relationship pre-selected in the form, e.g. an href like /nova/resources/programme/new?term_id=95 will load the Programme create page with Term 95 pre-selected.
Is there a Nova-friendly way to do this?
I can do this by putting the term_id from the request into the session from the newModel() method but this does not feel very clean.
